# use of limits after a non-math operator

Tags: subscripts

I would like to write the following:

```
$ \mu_{s,r} = \mbox{mean}_ {i \in N}(X_{i,s,r})$
```

but where the `{i \in N}` is underneath the word "mean". I tried `\limit` but it doesn't work unless it's a math operator. I understand this can ruin the look but I am making slides and want to see how it appears.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$ \underset{i \in N}{\operatorname{mean}}$
\end{document}
```

As egreg pointed out in the comments the following works too

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$ \operatorname*{mean}\limits_{n \in N}$
\[ \operatorname*{mean}_{n \in N}\] 
\end{document}
```

In a display style math environment you don't need to write `\limits`.

Comment: Throws an error. I think what you meant though was: 
    $\underset{\operatorname{i \in N}}{\mbox{mean}}$ which works.

Comment: @user1357015 It works now on my pc

Comment: What about `$\operatorname*{mean}\limits_{i\in N}$`? The `\limits` wouldn't be necessary in display math mode.

Comment: @egreg it works too (not surprising after you said it) i gonna add it to my answer

Comment: Revision fixed it! Many thanks :-).

Comment: The second solution is good, but I wouldn't recommend using `\underset`.

Comment: @HendrikVogt what is the problem with `\underset`

Comment: @Dominic: There's no _problem_ per se, but using subscripts with `_` (and possibly `\limits`) is just the standard way one should have in mind. I'm mostly talking about clarity of the code here.

Comment: @egreg What's the difference between star and non-star for `\operatorname`?

Comment: @neo With `\operatorname*{foo}`, limits are typeset above and below, in display style (or when `\limits` is specified).

Answer (score 8):

If you're using `beamer` you already load `amsmath`. However, in general, this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\mean}{mean}

\begin{document}
\section{Long version}

In line: $\mu_{s,r} = \operatorname*{mean}\limits_{i\in N}(X_{i,s,r})$

Displayed:
\[
\mu_{s,r} = \operatorname*{mean}\limits_{i\in N}(X_{i,s,r})
\]

\section{Short version}

In line: $\mu_{s,r} = \mean\limits_{i\in N}(X_{i,s,r})$

Displayed:
\[
\mu_{s,r} = \mean\limits_{i\in N}(X_{i,s,r})
\]

\end{document}
```

Of course you'll use only one of the methods. For a "one shot" operator, `\operatorname*` is easier. For several usages of the operator, the `\DeclareMathOperator*` way is better.

The difference between `\operatorname` and `\operatorname*` (reflected in usage of `\DeclareMathOperator` and `\DeclareMathOperator*`) is that the latter defines an operator that in displays takes limits above and below, like `\sum` or `\max`, and in inline formulas respects the presence of `\limits`.